# Need to localise IOS permission modals - how is this done?

Tags: ios, permissions, localization, multilingual

I've got an application on Google Play and the Apple app stores and they've been accepted many times, in fact, they've been updated 5 times. But on the last check with Apple, they ran the app in Spanish, instead of English. They refused the app because they said the app needed to show the right permission request. They showed me a screenshot of their using the app in Spanish, then a screenshot of a permission request modal's appearing before attemping to take a photo. The message was in English, so I'm assuming that that's what they're talking about. They were not specific and said merely "it didn't have the right permission". I'm assuming they meant it wasn't in the right language. I'm not going to ask Apple, because I've asked them questions before and they take a year to get back to you.

So, how do you put the IOS permissions in multiple languages? My app is in 7 languages...well, 5, but with both English languages (UK and US), and both French languages (FR and CA). At the moment, I've just got a super simple request, as the following:

```
<edit-config target="NSCameraUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>need camera access to take pictures</string>
</edit-config>
```

Foolishly, I completely forgot that IOS shows these messages. I don't particularly use any Apple products - and, of course, never used my app in France. I should have known that Apple shows these messages, but I didn't. Anyway, how can I show these messages in multiple languages? Obviously, tried searching the net but couldn't find correct answers.

I'm using phonegap.

Comment: I was just going to put them all in English and French. So while your here, how do also add line breaks in the '<string>' element? Is it '<br>' or '\n'?

Comment: You don't say environment you are using to develop your app. In Xcode you would simply add a localised version of info.plist

Comment: Sorry @Paulw11, I'm using phonegap.